# Mongo data index on SolrCloud

Tags: java, mongodb, solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am trying to use mongo-connector to index MongoDB collection into Solr for search feature I want to implement. If my collection in mongo has very nested JSON structure, will I be able to index that on Solr? What would the schema file in Solr look like if we want to index the json shown below?

```
"profile": {
   "id": "1234"
   "lastName": "Smith"
   "firstname" : "Daniel"
   "emails": {   
      "work": {
           "emailAddress": "abc@gmail.com", 
           "type": "work",          

       },

       "personal": {  
            "emailAddress": "nml@gmail.com", 
            "type": "personal",          

       }
    },
   "phones": {   
       "home": {
            "phoneNumber": "212345",     
        },
       "work": {
               "phoneNumber": "567899",   
        },
         "cell": {
               "phoneNumber": "112456",    
        }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [mongo connector automagically flattens documents](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage-with-Solr), so the field names would be:

```
"emails.work.emailAddress": "abc@gmail.com"
```

.. etc. That allows you to match the names through dynamic field defintions, where you can [give field names with wildcards to match multiple different names](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/dynamic-fields.html) to the same field definition:

```
<dynamicField name="emails.*" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

.. would index each field name that starts with `emails.` as a string field (which only allows exact matches).